# Module_Not_Found require stack error when i try to use ./(file location)

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

```py
FROM server.js file
var campground = require("./models/campground");  


   from campground.js file
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     name: "string",
     image: "string",
     description: "string",
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model("campground", campgroundSchema);
```

> I want to split my server.js file I try to use module.export() but its not working

Floder structure

first-app
models
views
public
server.js

Comment: Can you show your folder structure?

Comment: check the relative path for campground?

Comment: path is correct??

Comment: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628
Error: Cannot find module './models/campground'
Require stack:
- D:\web project\first-app\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\web project\first-app\server.js:5:18)
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\web project\\first-app\\server.js' ]
}